# How would I go about compiling IronPython for use in a .NET 3.5 project?

Tags: .net-3.5, ironpython

The website says it is for .NET 4.0 but that I could compile it for use with 3.5, however that is ALL it says on the topic as far as I can tell.

What files do I need? Any unique settings? Do I compile it in Visual Studio? Thanks..

I downloaded from here https://github.com/IronLanguages/main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used to work on the IronPython Team at Microsoft, but I know quite a bit has changed since 2.7 Alpha 1...

My suggestion is to stick with .NET 4.0 unless the machines you deploy to really cannot have 4.0 installed (e.g., lacking admin privileges to do the .NET install).  To attempt to make a really long story short, the guts of IronPython and IronRuby, the Dynamic Language Runtime, were added to .NET with version 4.0.  What this means for IronPython 2.6/2.7 is that it runs faster on .NET 4.0 when compared to .NET 3.5/3.0/2.0.  There's other good reasons to use the .NET 4.0 based assemblies as well, but this is the most compelling.

If you're just interested in compiling IronPython 2.7 and don't have Visual Studio 2010 installed...that's actually not a problem.  Install the full version of .NET 4.0 on your machine and use the version of msbuild that comes with it.  Path should be something like C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild

Finally, if you **really** must build against .NET 3.5, there used to be something like a "/version:3.5" flag you could pass to msbuild when compiling IronPython.sln.  Things have changed so much since the project left Microsoft's hands I really have no idea if this still works.  This is more likely to work with the last 2.6 release though - see http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/41236.  Flag for this might be "/version:2.0"?

Answer (score 1):

If its possible you would just load up the IronPython solution, change the target framework to 3.5 and compile the library.  Of course I seriously doubt it will work.

Comment: There was no IronPython solution in the source download .zip :(

Comment: So make your own solution and compile the code files like any other project?  I won't comment on that fact if you are even asking this question you have no business doing this.

Comment: @Ramhound yes I have checked that out now, sadly I only have Visual Studio 2008... and of course I have business doing this, how else do you learn things besides doing them eh?

Comment: So modify the solution to work with 2008 its about 4-5 lines at the most. If you must create the solutions yourself, again a simple task, besides the fact I see no reason you cannot reference a 4.0 dll with Visual Studio 2008 ( provided the 4.0 framework is installed )

Comment: @Ramhound I am simply trying to use it in a .NET 3.5 project, which is where the conflict arises